# Alert closed, but getting Unexpected alert open error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, alert

I have a scenario to create a new account, and I need to provide the account name in the popup and click "Ok".
I have used robot handling of the popup and on running the script, the alert closes and a new account is created, but getting the below error:

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open
>   (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.86) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I have tried the below code:

```
///String handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='createAccount']/p")).click();
Thread.sleep(300);
Robot rb =new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
Thread.sleep(200);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(400);
///driver.switchTo().window(handle);
//* Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
//*alt.accept();
// driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.findElement(By.id("passwd")).sendKeys("Abcd@123");
```

The commented lines are the solutions I got from google, but that's also not working.

Additional info: When I do

```
Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
alt.accept();
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

I get the below error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled
>   inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Could not handle JavaScript
>   dialog"} (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.86) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)      (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: I have the same problem.  It happens randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Since `thread.sleep()` requires `Exception` handling, you're probably throwing the exception to the caller?

Also, since you say it works, but simply reports the other exception error, perhaps you should place the code in a `try/catch` and trap any sleep `interruption exception` (don't recall the exact wording) and then also the other exception that it does report, and simply ignore both of those exceptions, but throw any other exceptions encountered.

I realize the goal (usually) is to find the cause and fix it, for now at least it can be ignored.